# SDK 5.4.0.GA Fails to build iOS Application

Tags: ios, appcelerator

Today, I upgraded to SDK 5.4.0 within `Appcelerator Studio`.

I changed the `tiapp.xml` to use 5.4.0 with this project.

It failed to build with the following error

```
[TRACE] :  CompileC build/Intermediates/REL.build/Debug-iphoneos/REL.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TiUITextWidget.o Classes/TiUITextWidget.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[TRACE] :      cd /Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone
[TRACE] :      export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
[TRACE] :      export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/chris/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/chris/opt/ant/bin:/Applications/usr/sdk/Android/tools:/Applications/usr/sdk/Android/platform-tools:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin"
[TRACE] :      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c99 -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wno-parentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEPLOYTYPE=test -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=7.1 -iquote /Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone/build/Intermediates/REL.build/Debug-iphoneos/REL.build/REL-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone/build/Intermediates/REL.build/Debug-iphoneos/REL.build/REL-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone/build/Intermediates/REL.build/Debug-iphoneos/REL.build/REL-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone/build/Intermediates/REL.build/Debug-iphoneos/REL.build/REL-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone/build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -Iheaders -I/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone/build/Intermediates/REL.build/Debug-iphoneos/REL.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone/build/Intermediates/REL.build/Debug-iphoneos/REL.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone/build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone/../../modules/iphone/au.com.mobilogica.wfios/1.0.1/platform -DDEBUG -include /Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone/build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/REL_Prefix-fnpnudzjjmqgaablsyfodhzdkqxp/REL_Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone/build/Intermediates/REL.build/Debug-iphoneos/REL.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TiUITextWidget.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone/build/Intermediates/REL.build/Debug-iphoneos/REL.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TiUITextWidget.dia -c /Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone/Classes/TiUITextWidget.m -o /Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone/build/Intermediates/REL.build/Debug-iphoneos/REL.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TiUITextWidget.o
[TRACE] :  In file included from /Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone/Classes/TiUITextWidget.m:14:
[TRACE] :  /Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone/Classes/TiApp.h:69:5: error: unknown type name 'UIApplicationShortcutItem'; did you mean 'UIApplicationState'?
[TRACE] :      UIApplicationShortcutItem *launchedShortcutItem;
[TRACE] :      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[TRACE] :      UIApplicationState
[TRACE] :  In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone/Classes/TiBase.h:10:
[TRACE] :  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:81:28: note: 'UIApplicationState' declared here
[TRACE] :  typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIApplicationState) {
[TRACE] :                             ^
[TRACE] :  In module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/iphone/Classes/TiEvaluator.h:9:
[TRACE] :  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:268:46: note: expanded from macro 'NS_ENUM'
[TRACE] :  #define NS_ENUM(_type, _name) CF_ENUM(_type, _name)
[TRACE] :                                               ^
[TRACE] :  In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from headers/JavaScriptCore/WebKitAvailability.h:53:
[TRACE] :  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFAvailability.h:171:50: note: expanded from macro 'CF_ENUM'
[TRACE] :  #define CF_ENUM(_type, _name) enum _name : _type _name; enum _name : _type
[TRACE] :                                                   ^
[TRACE] :  1 error generated.
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   CompileC build/Intermediates/REL.build/Debug-iphoneos/REL.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TiUITextWidget.o Classes/TiUITextWidget.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)
```

I changed back to a previous build, in fact I tried

- 5.2.1.GA
- 5.3.0.GA
- 5.3.1.GA

These all worked and built the app and it ran as expect.

I checked the `TiApp.h` mentioned and saw the reference to the type, which is an Apple defined type from UIKit. I found that all those versions listed also had a reference to `UIApplicationShortcutItem`.

I was wondering if anyone has found a similar issue and if they have figured out a resolution.

System:

- Mac OSX 10.10.5
- XCode 6.1
- Appcelerator CLI 5.4.0
- Appcelerator SDK 5.3.1

Comment: Try cleaning your project and compiling again. In Titanium Studio -> Project -> Clean...

Comment: Did that between each build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please upgrade Xcode to 7.3.1, it is a iOS 9 API that requires Xcode 7 or later. Thanks!

Comment: According to the Appcelerator Compatability Matrix 5.4.0 can be used with XCode 6.0.x through 7.x.

It seems to me that it is missing an #ifdef or something similar in the code.

At the moment, I am unable to goto 7.3.1 as we are using 10.10 and not 10.11 of OSX.

Basically, this is Appcelerator Generated code which appears to be broken.

Comment: We did not update the wiki before GA, sorry for that. Since the iOS9-APIs are all across the 5.4.0 release, wrapping everything manually was considered to be avoided. As we follow Apple's recommendations for new software, this was a product-management decision.

Comment: Hopefully the wiki will be updated real soon now, so others don't get stuck here.

Or maybe the upgrade to 5.4.0.GA should not be offered on system that do not support it.

Comment: Updated the matrix. The changes will as soon as the wiki is pushed again, thanks!

Comment: Thanks Hans. I appreciate your help with this.